# Reporting Services - aligning a right-to-left matrix

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, right-to-left, ssrs-tablix

In a RS report I have a matrix whose LayoutDirection property is set to RTL (because it's in Hebrew). I created a column group by dragging a field form the dataset field list and dropping it in the column header of the matrix. So the number of the columns is variable (which is OK).

When I view the report, the order of the columns is correct (from right to left). But the problem is that the matrix grows to the right and is always aligned to the left. The report is RTL, so I need the way around, i.e. I want the matrix to be aligned to the right and grow to the left.

I couldn't find a way to fix it. Could you please help me to solve this problem? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The way to fix it is by setting the property called "RightToLeft" in the "ReportViewer" control to "Yes".

The report viewer is the control which host and present the RDL. by default the report viewer set to left to right and not to RTL.

I have used it at my company and it works fine!

For more details look at this [post](http://www.hightechtalks.com/dotnet-framework-winforms-controls/reportviewer-right-left-223960.html)

Comment: Thanks, but the report is viewed directly in the RS server, not in a ReportViewer control.

Comment: So Unfortunately i don't think you can achieve it... I searched for a solution a lot time and haven't found one, but using the report viewer